# How to shorten code Javascript insert row

Tags: javascript

I have a small problem that I haven't been able to solve so far.
I wish I could shorten this piece of code, but I tried a `for loop` and failed.
Here is my code to shorten:

```
let Mrow = table.insertRow(12);
let Mcell0 = Mrow.insertCell(0);
let Mcell1 = Mrow.insertCell(1);
let Mcell2 = Mrow.insertCell(2);
let Mcell3 = Mrow.insertCell(3);
let Mcell4 = Mrow.insertCell(4);
Mcell0.innerHTML = "Totals";
Mcell1.innerHTML = Msum1; 
Mcell2.innerHTML = Msum2;
Mcell3.innerHTML = Msum3;
Mcell4.innerHTML = Msum4;type here
```

This is what i have tried:

```
for(let cell = 0; cell < 5; cell++){
    let Mrow = table.insertRow(12);
    let Mcell0 = Mrow.insertCell(cell);
    Mcell0.innerHTML = "Totals";
}
```

Unfortunately in this way I can't figure out how to do it.
However, by proceeding in this way, the code lengthens unnecessarily.
I know it might sound trivial, but I can't figure out how to do it and I'm wasting a lot of time.
Thank you all.
Sorry for the bad English.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can safely omit the indexes and eliminate temp variables:

```
let Mrow = table.insertRow(12);
Mrow.insertCell().innerHTML = "Totals"
Mrow.insertCell().innerHTML = Msum1
Mrow.insertCell().innerHTML = Msum2
Mrow.insertCell().innerHTML = Msum3
Mrow.insertCell().innerHTML = Msum4
```

Also, your serially number variables `MsumXXX` should probably be an array. If you can do that, you can reduce the last part to something like

```
for (let sum of MsumArray)
    Mrow.insertCell().innerHTML = sum
```

Comment: The idea of an Array is is brilliant! Now it works perfectly!

Answer (score 0):

one way of defining constant and extract it, it looks neater and code maintainability.
`const createCells= {0:'Totals',1:'Msum1',2:'Msum2'}; for(let [keys,values] of Object.entries(createCells)) {`dsdsd `console.log(keys,values) }`